# What's the inverse Laplace of 1/F(s)

Tags: laplace-transform

If we know that the inverse Laplace of $\ F(s)$  is $\ f(t)$ is it possible to find a relationship between $\ 1/F(s)$ and $\ f(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\lap}{\mathscr{L}}$Laplace transforms have the property $\lim_{s\to \infty} F(s) = 0$, for $s$ running over the reals. (recall that the Laplace transform, as an operator, is a mapping $\lap: L^2(0,\infty) \to H^2(\mathbb{C}^+)$). If $F(s)$ is the Laplace transform of some function $F$, then $\lim_{s\to \infty} \frac{1}{F(s)} = \infty$, therefore, $1/F$ does not have an inverse Laplace transform.

There is one exception which involves the Dirac "function".

Suppose there is a time-domain function $f$ so that $\lap f = F$. Suppose there exists a time-domain function $g$ so that $\lap g = \frac{1}{F}$. Then

$$
(\lap f)(s) \cdot (\lap g)(s) = F(s)\frac{1}{F(s)} = 1,
$$

so long as $s$ is not a zero of $F$. From the convolution theorem, $(\lap f)(s) \cdot (\lap g)(s) = \lap \{f * g\}(s)$, so

$$
\lap \{f * g\}(s) = 1 
\Rightarrow
f * g = \delta.
$$

One such pair is $f(t) = \delta(t)$ and $g(t) = 1$; another pair is $f(t) = \delta(t)$ and $g(t) = \delta(t)$.